# Should we promote cross referencing?

Tags: discussion, editing

As Skeptic.SE deals with many topics/effect/procedures/conditions etc that people may not be aware of, should we promote (by edits etc) cross referencing to other questions?

For instance, if I mention the placebo effect should I include a link to a relevant question like: [Is the placebo effect a purely psychological effect?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18/4) or event a [tag FAQ page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/placebo-effect?sort=faq&pagesize=15).

Comment: There's the "related" sidebar which automatically takes care of the likely related questions.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the question, really. It's not bad idea to leave a comment saying "related: [Is the placebo effect a purely psychological effect?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/is-the-placebo-effect-a-purely-psychological-effect)" It allows users who may not know of a question to check other questions, but **only to this is the overlap is significant enough**.